# Can I reuse my problem statement?

Tags: research-process, self-plagiarism

I am doing Master's of Research, and I am required to enrol in a number of compulsory coursework subjects for research candidates. In these subjects, I have submitted a number of assignments using Turnitin, which requires me to include the problem statement of my research.

Given that the problem statement hasn't changed every time I submit my assignments, am I supposed to write completely different problem statements every time I submit my assignments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, Turnitin is set to find similarities that are 3-4 words long at a minimum. So, is there a way to make minor edits so that your statement is slightly different each time? You can also ask your professor if it's okay to reuse your problem statements. Then, even if Turnitin flags it, your professor will know that they are still your words and ideas, since you discussed it ahead of time.

Comment: Making minor edits to my problem statement for no reason other than to avoid self-plagiarising seems unreasonable to me. I suppose all I can do is ask my lecturers beforehand.

Comment: Though it may seem unreasonable, if you are interested in pursuing academia as a career, learning how to rewrite your work over and over is a good skill...Journals use anti-plagiarism software, too, so if you write many papers on the same topic, you will have to learn how to do this anyway. For instance, one of my studies resulted in six papers, so I had to rewrite mundane parts of the first paper (e.g. methods) five times so that they wouldn't get flagged.